# Qt if else issue else doesnt works

Tags: qt, if-statement, authentication

Hello here's the code so if works and shows me message but else doesnt reacts doesnt shows any messages tried many things but always same when im entering right login and password its works if it's wrong it doesn't works tried also to make != same there

```
 if(db.open())
    {
        // Insert Query

        QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("MyConnection"));
        query.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");

        query.bindValue(":email", email);
        query.bindValue(":password", password);

        if(!query.exec())
        {
         QMessageBox::information(this,"Failed","Error please try again");
        }
        else
        {
            while(query.next())
            {
                    QString emailLog = query.value(1).toString();
                    QString passwordLog = query.value(4).toString();
                    if(emailLog == email && passwordLog == password){

                        QMessageBox::information(this,"SUCCESS","SUCCESS");
                        db.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ui->plstryagain->show();
                        db.close();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
   else
    {
       QMessageBox::information(this, "Database Error", "Can't Connect To Database");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else statement (you have many, and don't clearly specify which) will never run. if there is no hit for (user; pass) your while won't have anything to iterate. 
in fact, the `if(emailLog == email && passwordLog == password)` is redundant for the same reason.

Your snippet:

```
        while(query.next())
        {
                QString emailLog = query.value(1).toString();
                QString passwordLog = query.value(4).toString();
                if(emailLog == email && passwordLog == password){

                    QMessageBox::information(this,"SUCCESS","SUCCESS");
                    db.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    ui->plstryagain->show();
                    db.close();
                }
        }
```

**Maybe this is better:**

```
        if (query.hasNext()) {
            QMessageBox::information(this,"SUCCESS","SUCCESS");
            db.close();
        } else {
            ui->plstryagain->show();
            db.close();
        }
```

P/S:
  Whenever you think a basic language feature does not work, it's most likely to be your fault :P